# Can I do a diagonal line in CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want a design like this:

[image]

So in fact a left side with `background-color`, a right side with `background-color` (`divs` of course, easy).

But can I do a diagonal line with CSS?

Comment: SVG is a more powerful alternative for CSS here

Comment: Or use a simple background-image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separate 2 div's with slope line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777156/separate-2-divs-with-slope-line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this shape with a skewed pseudo element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/gyvprwex/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div>
    <h1>Your title here</h1>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    padding:0 10px 10px;
    background:#E7E5DD;

}
h1{
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    padding:10px 50px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
h1:before{
    content:'';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:-1;

    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have with with pure CSS - see

1. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ and
2. http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

(You would need a white top-left triangle on the gray area)

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
```

Please note that some browsers will not use anti-aliasing when drawing the borders.

A simpler approach in this case would be to have images for background - one for the text with the diagonal line, another one for the grey area.

Comment: Please post Code examples, cause the content of the links could be change

Comment: This is a wide-known principle of making triangles with CSS. If the content of the links changes, google search on "CSS triangle" would do.

Comment: Thanks for the Code Example. I know how to google, but the most people here dont google ... they ask directly

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/nuxcbqqq/1/

```
<div class="crossed"></div>

.crossed {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: 
   linear-gradient(to top left,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%),
   linear-gradient(to top right,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% - 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
       rgba(0,0,0,0) calc(50% + 0.8px),
       rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

Code from here [draw diagonal lines in div background with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012420/draw-diagonal-lines-in-div-background-with-css)